# Getting the handle of a loaded dylib

Tags: linux, macos, gcc, dylib

Suppose I load a dylib and discard the handle:

```
void loadfoo()
{
    dlopen("/lib/foo.dylib" , RTLD_NOW);
}
```

I then want to close it in another funciton:

```
void closefoo()
{
    dlclose // ???
}
```

Can I somehow find the handle of the previously loaded dylib if it's not been saved during the call to `dlopen`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I ever see such code in production, I hold the originator in eternal contempt, but:

```
void *handle = dlopen("/lib/foo.dylib", RTLD_NOW);
dlclose(handle);
dlclose(handle);
```